# The relation between the square of the integral and the integral of the square of the integrand

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $Y$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f$ be a $L^2$ function on $Y$. Then does the following formula always hold?

$$\left| \int_{Y} f\right|^2 \leq \int_{Y} |f|^2$$

I know that if $Y$ is a finite measure space, I can apply the Jensen's formula. But how about arbitrary cases? Could anyone please help me?

Comment: This is not true in general. Take $Y=\mathbb{R}$ (usual Lebesgue measure of the real line) and $f(x)=1/x$ for $x\geq 1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Not true even for finite measures. Let $f(x)=1$ for $ 0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $0$ for all other $x$ (Lebesgue measure).

The inequality is true for probability measures. This follows by Jensen's inequality applied ti the function $x \to x^{2}$.